# Running multiple sheets under one google script, syntax error

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to automate the refresh capability on my script. When I run the code below I get a syntax error at line 9 (arr.forEach ..) and am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
function multipleCallTr(){
  refreshPage1();
}


function refreshPage1() {

  const arr = ['testsheet1', 'testsheet2'];
  arr.forEach(element => {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(element), true);
  SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
  })
}
```

This code below works but obviously would be much better to run it through a loop statement as I'm trying above.

```
function multipleCallTr(){
  refreshPage1();
  refreshPage2(); 
}


function refreshPage1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('testsheet1'), true);
  SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
}

function refreshPage2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('testsheet2'), true);
  SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [enable V8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime)(if it's not enabled for you), to use ES6 syntax like the arrow `=>`

Answer (score 0):

solved it using this:

```
function multipleCallTr(){
  refreshPage1();
}


function refreshPage1() {

  i=0
  const arr = ['testsheet1', 'testsheet2'];
  for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++){

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(arr[i]), true);
  SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
  }
}
```